# How can I modify this LINQ query to dedupe the groupings?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm stuck in figuring out how to modify or extend my *LINQ* query to give me the *groupings* that I am desiring.

**Current code**

```
var alertlist = new List<AlertTest>();
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Twin Cities, MN", EventName = "Winter Storm Warning" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Twin Cities, MN", EventName = "Winter Storm Watch" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Twin Cities, MN", EventName = "Winter Storm Watch" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Twin Cities, MN", EventName = "Winter Storm Warning" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Twin Cities, MN", EventName = "Winter Weather Advisory" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Seattle, WA", EventName = "Flood Advisory" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Seattle, WA", EventName = "Gale Wind Warning" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Seattle, WA", EventName = "Wind Advisory" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Omaha, NE", EventName = "Severe Thunderstorm Watch" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Omaha, NE", EventName = "Severe Thunderstorm Watch" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Omaha, NE", EventName = "Severe Thunderstorm Warning" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Omaha, NE", EventName = "Tornado Watch" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Omaha, NE", EventName = "Tornado Watch" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Omaha, NE", EventName = "Tornado Watch" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Omaha, NE", EventName = "Tornado Watch" });
            alertlist.Add(new AlertTest { SenderName = "NWS Omaha, NE", EventName = "Tornado Watch" });

            var result =
                from a in alertlist
                orderby a.SenderName, a.EventName
                group a by new { a.SenderName, a.EventName };

            foreach (var AlertGroup in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{AlertGroup.Key.SenderName} ({AlertGroup.Count()})");
                foreach (AlertTest s in AlertGroup)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"  -- {s.EventName} ({AlertGroup.Count()})");
                }
            }
```

**Current output**

- NWS Omaha, NE (1)

  - Severe Thunderstorm Warning (1)
- NWS Omaha, NE (2)

  - Severe Thunderstorm Watch (2)
  - Severe Thunderstorm Watch (2)
- NWS Omaha, NE (5)

  - Tornado Watch (5)
  - Tornado Watch (5)
  - Tornado Watch (5)
  - Tornado Watch (5)
  - Tornado Watch (5)
- NWS Seattle, WA (1)

  - Flood Advisory (1)
- NWS Seattle, WA (1)

  - Gale Wind Warning (1)
- NWS Seattle, WA (1)

  - Wind Advisory (1)
- NWS Twin Cities, MN (2)

  - Winter Storm Warning (2)
  - Winter Storm Warning (2)
- NWS Twin Cities, MN (2)

  - Winter Storm Watch (2)
  - Winter Storm Watch (2)
- NWS Twin Cities, MN (1)

  - Winter Weather Advisory (1)

**Intended output**

- NWS Omaha, NE (8)

  - Severe Thunderstorm Warning (1)
  - Severe Thunderstorm Watch (2)
  - Tornado Watch (5)
- NWS Seattle, WA (3)

  - Flood Advisory (1)
  - Gale Wind Warning (1)
  - Wind Advisory (1)
- NWS Twin Cities, MN (5)

  - Winter Storm Warning (2)
  - Winter Storm Watch (2)
  - Winter Weather Advisory (1)

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you should group by SenderName property only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your *groupings*

```
var results = alertlist.OrderBy(a => a.SenderName)
                       .ThenBy(a => a.EventName)
                       .GroupBy(a => a.SenderName)
                       .Select(x => new
                           {
                              x.Key,
                              count = x.Count(),
                              EventNames = x.GroupBy(y => y.EventName)
                                            .Select(z => new
                                                {
                                                   z.Key,
                                                   Count = z.Count()
                                                })
                           });
```

or, if you don't want to *project* the *inner group*

```
var results = alertlist.OrderBy(a => a.SenderName)
                       .ThenBy(a => a.EventName)
                       .GroupBy(a => a.SenderName)
                       .Select(x => new
                           {
                              x.Key,
                              Count = x.Count(),
                              EventNames = x.GroupBy(y => y.EventName)
                           });
```

**Output**

```
NWS Omaha, NE (8)
  -- Severe Thunderstorm Warning (1)
  -- Severe Thunderstorm Watch (2)
  -- Tornado Watch (5)
NWS Seattle, WA (3)
  -- Flood Advisory (1)
  -- Gale Wind Warning (1)
  -- Wind Advisory (1)
NWS Twin Cities, MN (5)
  -- Winter Storm Warning (2)
  -- Winter Storm Watch (2)
  -- Winter Weather Advisory (1)
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kKgRu2)